# Unmarshalling a tuple that has no keys at the root level

Tags: go, json-deserialization

I'm trying to cut my teeth with golang, and figured parsing some json from a rest api is a good use case.  It looked to be as simple as defining a struct and unmarshaling the api response into that.

Naturally the api response I am playing with is not exactly a great candidate for this.  I am playing with craigslist jsonsearch - and the response is an array of 2 objects. The first object is an array of results, the second object is misc. metadata.

```
[  
   [  
      {  
         "Ask":6000,
         "CategoryID":145,
         "ImageThumb":"https:\/\/images.craigslist.org\/01212_dZ9PfxSmjEH_50x50c.jpg",
         "Latitude":39.591784,
         "Longitude":-105.083209,
         "PostedDate":1533949799,
         "PostingID":6642987803,
         "PostingTitle":"1991 Jeep Wrangler YJ 4.0 4X4 $6000 OBO",
         "PostingURL":"https:\/\/denver.craigslist.org\/cto\/d\/1991-jeep-wrangler-yj-40-4xobo\/6642987803.html"
      }
   ],
   {  
      "NonGeocoded":2,
      "baseurl":"\/\/denver.craigslist.org",
      "clat":41.2077284889441,
      "clng":-101.993919320865,
      "clustered":0,
      "geocoded":118,
      "zoom":7
   }
]
```

The fact that neither of these objects have keys is where I am getting lost.

I have created a struct that I believe should map to this response.  Without keys to as field tags, I am lost...  If there was only some way to say the first element in the response should map the the Results[] struct and the second item to the Metadata struct.

```
type SearchResponse struct {
    Results []struct {
        Ask int
        CategoryID int
        ImageThumb string
        Latitude float32
        Longitude float32
        PostedDate int64
        PostingID int64
        PostingTitle string
        PostingURL string
    }`json:"??first element??"`
    Metadata struct{
        NonGeocoded int
        baseurl string
        clat float32
        clng float32
        clustered int
        geocoded int
        zoom int
    }`json:"??second element??"`
}


func main() {

    searchUrl := "https://denver.craigslist.org/jsonsearch/cta?query=jeep+wrangler&sort=rel&max_price=15000&auto_transmission=1"
    resp, _ := http.Get(searchUrl)
    bytes, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)

    var searchResp SearchResponse
    if err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, &searchResp); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Print("it worked!")
    resp.Body.Close()

}
```

Is there a easier/better way to do this?

Comment: The json is an array, a Go struct is treated by the json package as an object. `[ ... ]` and `type SearchResponse struct { ... }` does not compute.

Comment: If your json is an array use Go slices, if it's an object use structs, or maps... https://play.golang.org/p/EYE4m76ngj7

Comment: Another option would be to have `SearchResponse` implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface, then it could, for example, remove the surrounding angle brackets, split the array of results from the meta object and the unmarshal then two jsons separately into the two fields.

Comment: Small fix on the playground example, to actually unmarshal all fields & log them in a clearer way: https://play.golang.org/p/IA6-QpeWDW5

Comment: i appreciate both of your playground examples - they both are legitimate answers.  i would gladly accept either as the final answer - post as an answer instead of comment.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this one https://github.com/Anderson-Lu/gofasion. It's easy.

Gofasion is a lightweight parsing library that facilitates the parsing of interface JSON data during development. Its biggest feature is to support chained calls, which means that the target key name and key value can be directly obtained without pre-defining the structure of the data.